# How to use Weka DECORATE meta-learner for ensembles in python?

Tags: python, weka, ensemble-learning

I would like to use the following WEKA Package:
[Class Decorate](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/meta/Decorate.html) that implements the DECORATE meta-learner for ensembles in python. What is the most efficient way to do it?